# Redefine a master head?

Tags: git

I have a repo where the commits has gone from:

`... C1 ... C2 ... C3 ... Cn` on master branch, Let's say I found out only at `Cn` commit point that the code has major issues that will take time to debug, and I want to have a stable/good Master asap. Suppose I know `C3` is the last known good point. Is there a way for me to **redefine** master head as `C3`, and label `Cn` as a new branch head, say "debug" branch? (the repo is remote, but let's say it is not publically shared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

In Git, *master* is just another branch label that points to a given commit. Technically, you don't even need a branch named *master* to exist within the repository at all.

Your two best options are `git-checkout` and `git-reset`, depending on whether you want to move or discard history. The former is what you asked for, while the latter is included for completeness.

### Using Checkout

You can do what you want by resetting the master branch to an arbitrary commit. For example:

```
# Move current master branch aside.
git branch -m master debug

# Create a new branch at committish. Use a branch name or a commit ID.
git checkout -b master c3
```

### Using Reset

Alternatively, if you don't care about your existing history, the fastest solution is just to reset the HEAD of *master* to a committish. For example, assuming you are already on the master branch:

```
git reset --hard c3
```

While this won't leave your current history available in the master branch, the full history will still be accessible via the reflog until pruned.

Answer (score 2):

So if your branch of `master` looks like

```
... C1 ... C2 ... C3 ... Cn
```

You could do the following:

Get the current version of `master` that looks like above

```
git checkout master
```

Make a new branch that will hold onto `Cn` for you

```
git checkout -b debug_branch
```

Checkout `master` again so you can fix it

```
git checkout master
```

Roll-back the commit to get it into a good state

```
git reset --hard C3
```

Push this version of `master` back up to the remote, which will "erase" the `Cn` commit

```
git push -f
```

Now you can locally go back to that debug branch to figure out what the problem is

```
git checkout debug_branch
```

Comment: [`git checkout -b debug_branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is a shortcut for `git branch debug_branch` followed by `git checkout debug_branch`. Keep only the first part (the branch creation) and there is no need to checkout `master` again after that.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -M master debug
git checkout -b master C3
git push -f
```

or (when trying to stay mergeable):

```
git branch -M master debug      # same as above
git checkout -b master C3       # same as above
git merge -s ours debug
git push
```